# How to get user's detail from related table with MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables that looks like this:

Users

```
id | name | password 
------------------------
2  | John | ******
3  | Ben  | ******
4  | Dan  | ******
```

UserHobbies

```
id | user_id | hobbie_id
-------------------------
 1 |   2    | 1
 2 |   2    | 3
 3 |   3    | 1
 4 |   4    | 2
```

Hobbies

```
id | HobbieName
------------------------
 1 | Surfing
 2 | Walking
 3 | Soccer
```

I want to find the user's related hobbies so the result will look like this:

```
username | HobbieName | hobbie_id
------------------------
   John  | Surfing    |    1
   Ben   | Surfing    |    1
```

As you can see - users John and Ben have the same hobby - 'Surfing', so the result will display ONLY them.

Here is what i've done so far -

```
SELECT users.name, hobbies.hobbie_name,  COUNT(user_hobbies.hobby_id)   FROM 
user_hobbies 
INNER JOIN users on user_hobbies.user_id = users.id
INNER JOIN hobbies ON hobbies.id = user_hobbies.hobby_id
GROUP BY user_hobbies.hobby_id
```

And the result :

```
name | hobbie_name | count
---------------------------
 dan |  Surfing    |  2
```

As you can see - i get the count of each hobbie - rather then a row with the user and the hobbie

Comment: How about `GROUP BY users.id, user_hobbies.hobby_id`?

Comment: Wait, are you looking to find `hobbie_id` per user or how many `COUNT` of hobbies per user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get only the hobbies that have multiple users, join with a subquery that counts the number of users per hobby.

```
SELECT users.name, hobbies.hobbie_name, user_hobbies.hobby_id
FROM user_hobbies 
INNER JOIN users on user_hobbies.user_id = users.id
INNER JOIN hobbies ON hobbies.id = user_hobbies.hobby_id
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT hobby_id
    FROM user_hobbies
    GROUP BY hobby_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AS multiple ON multiple.hobby_id = user_hobbies.hobby_id
```

Comment: The desired results suggest to add `WHERE hobbies.id = 1` or `WHERE hobbies.hobbie_name = 'Surfing'`.

Comment: Maybe, I thought he was just showing a sample of results. There's nothing in the text that suggests he only wants one jobby.

Comment: Thanks, i've updated the desired result - i want to show ONLY hobbies that's related to multiple users, so if ''Surfing" is related to 2 users - then the results will be - User name ( John) - Hobby_name ('Surfing'), and in the next row - User name ( Ben) - Hobby_name ('Surfing'),

Answer (score 0):

Could use WHERE too: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/241cfd/4/0

**Data**

```
create table users (id INT, name VARCHAR(20), password VARCHAR(20));
create table user_hobbies (id INT, user_id INT, hobby_id INT);
create table hobbies (id INT, name VARCHAR(20));

INSERT INTO users VALUES (2, 'John', '**********');
INSERT INTO users VALUES (3, 'Ben', '**********');
INSERT INTO users VALUES (4, 'Dan', '**********');

INSERT INTO user_hobbies VALUES (1, 2, 1);
INSERT INTO user_hobbies VALUES (2, 2, 3);
INSERT INTO user_hobbies VALUES (3, 3, 1);
INSERT INTO user_hobbies VALUES (4, 4, 2);

INSERT INTO hobbies VALUES (1, 'Surfing');
INSERT INTO hobbies VALUES (2, 'Walking');
INSERT INTO hobbies VALUES (3, 'Soccer');
```

**SQL**

```
SELECT u.name, h.name AS hobby, uh.hobby_id
FROM user_hobbies AS uh
INNER JOIN users AS u ON uh.user_id = u.id
INNER JOIN hobbies AS h ON h.id = uh.hobby_id
WHERE uh.hobby_id = 1;
```

**Result**

```
| name |   hobby | hobby_id |
|------|---------|----------|
| John | Surfing |        1 |
|  Ben | Surfing |        1 |
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks buddy! i'll taks a look